# PHP's exec() printing output -- doesn't seem to follow specs

Tags: php, exec

One of my users is experiencing odd behavior that doesn't seem to follow the PHP [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) specs.

I'm invoking like so:

```
exec($cmd, $out, $ret);
```

I would expect this not to generate any output, but the user is seeing an error stack trace from `$cmd` printed when it errors out. Nothing in my code outputs anything, so it has to be coming out of `exec()`, but how? Am I misinterpreting the documentation?

I expect I could trap this inside of an output buffer then dispose of it, but I would rather prevent it... And whatever I do, I want to understand why this is happening first.

NOTE: I'm working on getting more specifics on PHP version and other d etails from the users, but do not have that information at this time. All I can say is that it is >= 5.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you experience is the normal unix behaviour:

An executed command always has *two* output pipes: standard out and error out. The documentation states that all output is given back. That does *not* include stuff written to the error output. That is using a separate pipe py purpose to separate error and normal output. If you want to capture that too you have to change the command you execute, typically you map the error output to the standard output by appending a `2>&1`.

Comment: Ah-ha! Interesting. Seems like PHP could document that a bit better, but now that you say that, makes perfect sense.